# How to adjust scroll height of Xaml StackLayout?

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I have a StackLayout which has items dynamically added to it when a user is selected. I want it to have a height of around 200, then if the list is longer than this, it should be scrollable.

If I add a height request to it as it is now, it adjusts the height and the scrollbar works but prevents items being added after the bottom of the box (so the scrollbar is basically pointless.

This is the code, the StackLayout is called 'readout':

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Clocker.MainPage" >
  <StackLayout x:Name="mainstack">
    <Picker x:Name="locationpicker" SelectedIndexChanged="locationpicker_SelectedIndexChanged" BackgroundColor="#baf4d5"></Picker>
    <Label x:Name="timeLabel" FontSize="50" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="#59a092"/>
    <ScrollView Orientation="Vertical" BackgroundColor="#baf4d5">
      <StackLayout x:Name="readOut">

      </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <ListView x:Name="userslist" BackgroundColor="#59a092">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
            <ViewCell.ContextActions>
              <MenuItem Clicked="OnIn" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                 Text="In" />
              <MenuItem Clicked="OnOut" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                 Text="Out" IsDestructive="True" />
            </ViewCell.ContextActions>
            <StackLayout Padding="15,0">
              <Label x:Name="lblname" Text="{Binding FullName}" TextColor="White" />
            </StackLayout>
          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've 2 or 3 pages in my app that are more or less like what you described.
My solution uses  and 2 lists.
More or less like this:

```
        <Grid ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="8*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Row 1 is where I have my first list, row 2 is where the second list goes.

I do it this way (0 is a header and 3 is a footer), so I have more or less 20% of the left space on top and the rest of the space allocated for the second list.

Hope it's clear.

Comment: I believe that will proportion the items on screen but I don't think it will do anything to solve the problem of the stacklayout not scrolling.